# How do I use the Gmail API with a account that doesn't end in "@gmail.com"?

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I got an email account that is managed by a business that uses the Gmail interface. Basically, I don't sign in through gmail.com, and my account address doesn't end in @gmail.com, but the email itself is managed by Gmail.

I would like to use Python to access the Gmail API on this account. How would I go about setting that up? The [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) doesn't mention setting up credentials on an alternative domain.

Comment: You can access the developer console as the Google Apps user.

Comment: Not sure how to access the developer console. When I log into my account, it just takes me to the inbox.

Comment: Go to https://console.developers.google.com/. Log in with your Google Apps account. If you're already logged in as a Gmail user, log out first (or just hit "Add Account" in the dialog that pops up if you click your avatar in the top-right).

Comment: Hey that worked! Will you type that into an answer, so I can select it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the process is almost no different for an email address managed by gmail and an actual @gmail.com address. As ceejayoz mentioned in his comment, just go to the developers [console](http://console.developers.google.com) after signing into your email through whatever sign in form the business in question has set up. From there you can set up credentials the same way you would for any gmail account.